# How to find all .zip and .rar files recursively and sort them by size

Tags: find, ls, disk-usage

I am looking for all .zip and .rar files in comp_tuts folder and I am intersted in showing their file sizes and sorting them from biggest to smallest.

I have tried

```
ls -R *.zip

ls: cannot access *.zip: No such file or directory
```

What??

I have tried this:

```
find / size +50M */comp_tuts/*.zip
```

For some reasong it's completely ignoring my path and starts at /usr/lib or whereever.

I have also tried

```
du -sh *.zip
du: cannot access ‘*.zip’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible duplicate Link answered the question partly.
To provide multiple name patterns to 'find' use this

```
find $directory -type f \( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.rar" \)
```

The complete answer to the question is:

```
find $directory -type f \( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.rar" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 du -b | sort -n -r
```

with $directory being comp_tuts/ dir

Comment: Please explain your answer and I'll mark it as answer

Comment: Did you check the Link provided by Evgeny? It is pretty well explained there. I just added the first part with find being able to look for .zip aswell as .rar

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- **/*.(rar|zip)(DoL)
```

Replace with `ls -lUd --` if you want to see `ls -l` information about them (`-U` being a GNU extension).

Note that it sorts by size, not disk usage.

Comment: I get bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Marko-A, I did say _with zsh_. `zsh` is a different shell from `bash`.